# Leaderboards giving no scores

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, leaderboard

I have an iPhone application with leaderboards. The submission of scores work successfully and at the leaderboards page show "1 of 1 player" and "1 of 1 friend" under/above the leaderboard. But when I click on the leaderboard, I get "No Scores". Is there a reason why my name doesn't appear?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not enough Information to help here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody faces this problem again, it is not from your side. I just left it for couple of hours and found it working.